# Embedding a dynamically generated form into another

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

I use Symfony2.1's FormBuilder to create a dynamic form in the controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData);
$form->add('field','text');
```

I would like to embed another form in the same way and embed it with the main form.

```
$subForm = $this->createFormBuilder();
$subForm->add('subfield','text');

// Does not work
$form->add('subform', $subForm);
```

Unfortunately this setup does not work properly. I could not find any way how to add a dynamically generated subform into a dynamically generated form, like the example above.

What's the function call I am missing?

The exception thrown by the example code above is

> UnexpectedTypeException: Expected argument of type "string or
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface",
>   "Symfony\Component\Form\Form" given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recommended symfony-way is to create separate FormType classes, as mentioned above. But if you really want to..

You can add dynamic subform into form builder, by calling

```
$formBuilder->add($subform /* FormBuilder */);
```

This subform will have name `"form"` if created with `$this->createFormBuilder();` , that means that you can not add two or more subforms created this way - newer one will overwrite previous with same name.

If you need to add multiple sub-forms, you have to create their builders with

```
$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder($uniqName)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution fits to the scope of my original (and old) question very well. The key is indeed the call to `FormFactory::createNamedBuilder()`.

Comment: Sometimes you don't really want to, but really need to :) This is the best answer, no idea why the other one has so many upvotes.

Answer (score 9):

I would create two Form Clases in two separate fields:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FirstFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('field', 'text')
            ->add('subform', new SecondFormType());
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\FirstEntity'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'first';
    }
}



<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SecondFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('subfield', 'text');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\SecondEntity',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'second';
    }
}
```

After this creation you can create your form from any Controller with this line for creation forms:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FirstFormType());
```

or for edition forms:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FirstFormType(), $first);
```

In your example code you are trying to assig to a field an entire form instead of a Form Type.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Without making classes... inside a Controller Action:

```
$subFormBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder(
        null /* default data */, 
        ['label' => 'Sub Form'] /* options */
    )
    ->add('name');

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add($subFormBuilder)
    ->add('number')
    ->getForm();
```